# How to Execute Selenium Python Online

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, scheduled-tasks

I have a selenium python file and then I want to run the program online without turning on the computer
how can I run the program without the windows task scheduler and the computer running?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.smkn2godean.sch.id/artikel/ppdb-smkn-2-godean-tahun-2020")

element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Tinggalkan Komentar").click()

element = driver.find_element_by_name("nama").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_name("nama").send_keys("Joss")

element = driver.find_element_by_name("email").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("joss@gmail.com")

element = driver.find_element_by_name("komentar").click()
element = driver.find_element_by_name("komentar").send_keys("joss2")

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn").click()
```

Comment: **_I want to run the program online_** online where ? on cloud ? this seems as we can't make a call until and unless turn on the phone and dial the number

Comment: i have a cpanel or hosting, can i run with hosting or at cpanel?

Comment: I do this on a server where I SSH into the virtual machine in the cloud and simply run my selenium python script from there. I use cron to schedule the running of the python script. Is something like that what you are looking for?